# Can't get jqGrid integrated search toolbar working?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have been following the example from http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/search3.html

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My First Grid</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="includes/jquery/plugins/jqgrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<script src="includes/jquery/plugins/jqgrid/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="includes/jquery/plugins/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="includes/jquery/plugins/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'index.php/jqgrid/customer',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames:['ID','Creator', 'Firstname','Surname','Address 1','Address 2', 'Address 3', 'City', 'County', 'Postcode',
                'Country', 'Email', 'Home Tel', 'Mobile Tel', 'Work Tel', 'Notes'],
    colModel :[
      {name:'id', index:'id', width:55},
      {name:'creator_id', index:'creator_id', width:80},
      {name:'firstname', index:'firstname', width:80},
      {name:'surname', index:'surname', width:80},
      {name:'address_1', index:'address_1', width:80},
      {name:'address_2', index:'address_2', width:80},
      {name:'address_3', index:'address_3', width:80},
      {name:'city', index:'city', width:80},
      {name:'county', index:'county', width:80},
      {name:'postcode', index:'postcode', width:80},
      {name:'country', index:'country', width:80},
      {name:'email', index:'email', width:80},
      {name:'home_tel', index:'home_tel', width:80},
      {name:'mobile_tel', index:'mobile_tel', width:80},
      {name:'work_tel', index:'work_tel', width:80},
      {name:'notes', index:'notes', width:80}
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    sortname: 'id',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'My first grid'
  });
});

$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:true,refresh:true});
$("#list").jqGrid('navButtonAdd',"#pager",{caption:"Toggle",title:"Toggle Search Toolbar", buttonicon :'ui-icon-pin-s',
        onClickButton:function(){
                $("#list")[0].toggleToolbar()
        }
});
$("#list").jqGrid('navButtonAdd',"#pager",{caption:"Clear",title:"Clear Search",buttonicon :'ui-icon-refresh',
        onClickButton:function(){
                $("#list")[0].clearToolbar()
        }
});
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar');

</script>

</head>
<body>
<table id="list"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The example is loading all css,js files and inputs the data fine. But will not show any buttons on the bottom toolbar or adding the search toolbar at the top.

Comment: @motionman95 Console has no errors.

Comment: I've not used jqGrid, but what does "jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar');" do?

Comment: @motionman95 I have changed it to $("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar'); and it has something to do with creating the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

just change

$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:true,refresh:true});

with

jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#list-pager',{del:true,add:true,edit:true},{},{modal: true,afterSubmit:processAddEdit, afterComplete:reloadJqGrid, recreateForm:true},{},{multipleSearch:true});

Hope it works..just try as not quite sure just thought of a different syntax..